# Result is Not Displayed After Pressing the button

Tags: apex, visualforce-component

I am new in Salesforce Coding. I am doing some practice in apex and visualforce page. I have one scenario here. Once I fill the form , land on next page. On this new page, when I click on 'Total Charges' button, it should display the value in 'Total Charges' field.

The problem is here, I am getting total charges in 'Debug Log' but it is not displaying in the field.

Here I am attaching the code.

```
public class VisitorRegistrationView {   
    public Visitor__c visitor{get;set;}   
    public VisitorRegistrationView()
    {
        Id id = apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().get('Id');
        visitor=[
            select Id,name,CountryName__c,Passport_Number__c,Covid_19_Symtomp__c,SendToQuarantineCenter__c,CanVisitorGoToHome__c,Quarantine_Cetner__c,PatientEntryDate__c,Patient_Exit_Date__c,TotalCharges__c 
            from Visitor__c 
            WHERE Id=:id
        ];
    } 

    public Void VisitorStayCharges(){

        Integer p_day_charge=500;

        Integer noOfDays = visitor.PatientEntryDate__c.daysBetween(visitor.Patient_Exit_Date__c);
        Integer TotalCharges = p_day_charge*noOfDays;
        // PageReference pageRef;
        //pageRef =  new PageReference('/apex/TotalCharges');
        //  return TotalCharges; 
    }

}
```

---

```
<apex:page controller="VisitorRegistrationView" showHeader="false" sidebar="false">
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock title="Visitor Detail Page">
            <apex:pageBlockButtons location="top">
                <apex:commandButton value="New" reRender="true" action="{!newRecord}"/>
                <apex:commandButton value="Edit" reRender="true" action="{!UpdatenewRecord}"/>
                <apex:commandButton value="Cancel" reRender="true" action="{!CancelRecord}"/>
                <apex:commandButton action="{!VisitorStayCharges}" value="Total Charges" />
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>
            <apex:pageBlockSection title="Visitor Information " collapsible="true">
                <apex:outputField value="{!visitor.Name}"/><br/>
                <apex:outputField value="{!visitor.CountryName__c}"/><br/>
                <apex:outputField value="{!visitor.Passport_Number__c}"/><br/>
                <apex:outputField value="{!visitor.Covid_19_Symtomp__c}"/><br/>
                <apex:outputField value="{!visitor.SendToQuarantineCenter__c}"/><br/>
                <apex:outputField value="{!visitor.CanVisitorGoToHome__c}"/><br/>
                <apex:outputField value="{!visitor.Quarantine_Cetner__c}"/><br/>
                <apex:outputField value="{!visitor.PatientEntryDate__c}"/><br/>
                <apex:outputField value="{!visitor.Patient_Exit_Date__c}"/><br/>
                <apex:outputField value="{!visitor.TotalCharges__c}"/><br/>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
            <apex:pageBlockSection columns="2" title="List of Visitor Record">
                <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!List_of_Visitor_Less_Than_18Yrs}" var="v" >
                    <apex:column value="{!v.Name}"/>
                    <apex:column value="{!v.Age__c}"/>
                    <apex:column value="{!v.CountryName__c}"/>
                </apex:pageBlockTable>
                <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!List_of_Visitor_More_Than_18Yrs}" var="v1" >
                    <apex:column value="{!v1.Name}"/>
                    <apex:column value="{!v1.Age__c}"/>
                    <apex:column value="{!v1.CountryName__c}"/>
                </apex:pageBlockTable>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are assigning all your calculations to local variables

```
Integer p_day_charge=500;

Integer noOfDays = visitor.PatientEntryDate__c.daysBetween(visitor.Patient_Exit_Date__c);
Integer TotalCharges = p_day_charge*noOfDays;
```

And I guess you want to display it in here

```
<apex:outputField value="{!visitor.TotalCharges__c}"/><br/>
```

So you would need to just change the last line I quoted of the controller by

```
// Integer TotalCharges = p_day_charge*noOfDays;
visitor.TotalCharges__c = p_day_charge*noOfDays;
```

and don't forget !!, this is **NOT** stored on the database, you would need to do a

```
update visitor;
```

if you want your changes to apply to the database (and do some error checks with try-catch, show  on the visualforce, etc.

Comment: Thanks Sergio, It worked as you explained.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a global variable to hold the value of total charge field. Instead storing the value to a local variable, store it in the global and use getter setter to make the value accessible from vf page.

I've updated your code,

```
public class VisitorRegistrationView {
public Visitor__c visitor{get;set;}
public Integer totalCharges{get;set;}
public VisitorRegistrationView() { Id id = apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().get('Id'); visitor=[select Id,name,CountryName__c,Passport_Number__c,Covid_19_Symtomp__c,SendToQuarantineCenter__c,CanVisitorGoToHome__c,Quarantine_Cetner__c,PatientEntryDate__c,Patient_Exit_Date__c,TotalCharges__c from Visitor__c WHERE Id=:id]; }

public Void VisitorStayCharges(){

    Integer p_day_charge=500;

    Integer noOfDays = visitor.PatientEntryDate__c.daysBetween(visitor.Patient_Exit_Date__c);
     totalCharges = p_day_charge*noOfDays;
   // PageReference pageRef;
    //pageRef =  new PageReference('/apex/TotalCharges');
        //  return TotalCharges; 
}

}
```

If you've any doubt. Please post them here.

Comment: Thanks Sachin for your reply. I understood, what you suggested.